# Are there any more general (or similar) results in the same spirit as Friedlander–Iwaniec theorem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

[Friedlander–Iwaniec theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedlander%E2%80%93Iwaniec_theorem) tells that there are an infinite number of primes of the form $a^2+b^4$.

> Are there any more general results? If not more general, are there any results for some other different exponents $\neq 1$ other than $2$ and $4$? What is the current state-of-the-art for problems like this one?

Comment: This is the only similar result that I know of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heath-Brown proved there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^3+2y^3$. It's discussed in Glyn Harman's book, Prime-Detecting Sieves. The original reference is D R Heath-Brown, Primes represented by $x^3+2y^3$, Acta Math 186 (2001) 1-84.

Comment: Is that result of Heath-Brown, the result of Friedlander–Iwaniec, and Fermat˛s theorem on sums of two squares almost all that is known in this direction?

Comment: The Fermat result is much, much easier than the other two, and a considerable amount is known about other binary quadratic forms (such as $x^2+3y^2$). So far as I know, Friedlander-Iwaniec and Heath-Brown are the only two-variable results about higher degrees.

Comment: See also https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00531 (Heath-Brown and Li, Prime values of $a^2+p^4$). Also worth a look is http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Friedlander-Iwaniec_theorem

Comment: Is it expected that there will also be an infinitude of primes if we switch $x$ with $p$ or $y$ with $p$  in the $x^3+2y^3$ result?